# System.Text.GetBytes cuts my data short, fix?

Tags: c#, arrays, client-server, byte

So I have this function:

```
byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
```

I am sending the resulting byte array over network to the client. Problem is that the input string data is rather long and this converts it to array of size of only 33, which I already know is not enough and of course on the client side when i convert back to string it is like 1/10 of the string. Any idea what is this caused by?

In case it is relevant the input string is:

```
MSH|^~\&|NEMEC APP|FBMI MENTAL HEALTH INSTITUTE|CLIENT APP|CLIENT FACILITY|20180529201338||ORU^R01^ORU_R01|20110614000009|P|2.4|||NE|AL|Czechia|ASCII||ASCII
PID|||2011021||Name||Date|O|||Address|
PV1||I|^^OR-1^10.2.56.5:1
ORC|RE
OBR|1|||VITAL|||20110616122516||||||||||||||||||A
OBX|1|NM|_001000^VITAL HR|1|92|bpm|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|2|NM|_002000^VITAL VPC|1|0|/min|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|3|NM|_003000^VITAL ST1|1|0.00|mV|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|4|NM|_003001^VITAL ST2|1|0.02|mV|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|5|NM|_003002^VITAL ST3|1|0.02|mV|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|6|NM|_003003^VITAL STVR|1|-0.01|mV|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|7|NM|_003004^VITAL STVL|1|0.00|mV|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|8|NM|_003005^VITAL STVF|1|0.02|mV|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|9|NM|_004001^VITAL APSEC(RESP)|1|1|sec|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|10|NM|_004073^VITAL rRESP(co2)|1|16|/min|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|11|NM|_007000^VITAL SpO2|1|99|%|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|12|NM|_007001^VITAL PR(spo2)|1|90|/min|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|13|NM|_028000^VITAL TEMP2|1|24.1|C|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|14|NM|_044000^VITAL ART(S)|1|87|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|15|NM|_044001^VITAL ART(D)|1|50|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|16|NM|_044002^VITAL ART(M)|1|65|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|17|NM|_044006^VITAL PR(art)|1|90|/min|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|18|NM|_052000^VITAL PAP(S)|1|30|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|19|NM|_052001^VITAL PAP(D)|1|6|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|20|NM|_052002^VITAL PAP(M)|1|16|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|21|NM|_053000^VITAL CVP(S)|1|17|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|22|NM|_053001^VITAL CVP(D)|1|7|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|23|NM|_053002^VITAL CVP(M)|1|8|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|24|NM|_058000^VITAL ICP(S)|1|300|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|25|NM|_058001^VITAL ICP(D)|1|300|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|26|NM|_058002^VITAL ICP(M)|1|300|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|27|NM|_058003^VITAL CPP|1|-235|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|28|NM|_072044^VITAL rPR(art)|1|90|/min|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|29|NM|_073000^VITAL RESP(co2)|1|16|/min|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|30|NM|_073001^VITAL EtCO2|1|48.0|mmHg|||||F|||20110616122516|||
OBX|31|NM|_073003^VITAL APSEC(CO2)|1|1|sec|||||F|||20110616122516|||
;n
```

While after converting back from the byte array on the client side only this remains:

```
MSH|^~\&|NEMEC APP|FBMI MENTAL HEALTH INSTITUTE|CLIENT APP|CLIENT FACILITY|20180529201338||ORU^R01^ORU_R01|20110614000009|P|2.4|||NE|AL|Czechia|ASCII||ASCII
PID|||2011021||Name||Date|O|||Address|
PV1||I|^^OR-1^10.2.56.5:1
ORC|RE
OBR|1|||VITAL|||20110616122
```

So for the actual code:

string data is equal to above, up until this point there is no problem. 
What follows on server side:

```
byte[] msg=System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
```

While on client side is the sendReceive function that takes care of sending a request and getting the response.

```
static string sendRec(string message)
{
    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    data = new Byte[256];

    String responseData = String.Empty;
    Int32 bytes         = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    responseData        = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

    return responseData;
}
```

However I ma reasonably sure, that the problem occurs on the server side.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that `msg.Length == 33` on the server. I tested your code and `msg.Length` was 2372.  Please post code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you Ed, I have updated the question with relevant code.

Comment: Why are you "reasonably sure" the problem occurs on the server side? It does or it doesn't, and it's easy to find out which. What is the value of `msg.Length` that you pass to `stream.Write()`? Please explain. Your `sendRec()` method can't read more than 256 bytes, by the way.